Is it possible to search for static function references in VS Code only in the file in which they are defined?
I am using a Microsoft C/C++ extension in VS Code, and I cannot find references to a static function only in the file in which it is defined.
In my workspace, I have a static function with the same name defined in multiple .c files, and searching for a reference to it is very time consuming as it goes to search all of those files.
When I was using Eclipse, that did not happen. Can I make it work the same way?
I looked for some item in the extension settings, but could not find it.
I also tried changing the settings in the C configuration file, but did not see any change.

Welcome to SO. If you are only looking in a single file, you could simply use Ctrl-F.

CTRL+SHIFT+F will let you find in the whole workspace

What I mean is, "When I do a References: Find All References in Command Center for a static function, is there a way to make it search only for the file I am defining?"

@Raildex searching in all the other files seems to be what the OP wants to avoid.

Why would you insist on using a function that isintented to search a whole workspace if simpe search function already does the job for a single file?

If there are no functions of the same name in other files, "Find all References" will find them with no problem. I just want to do the same thing.
Currently, VS Code searches all files and then gives me a bunch of "not a reference" entries, but since it searches for references to static functions, it is obvious that the ones in other files are not references.

I cannot repro with a CMake Tools + Cpptools setup with GCC and functions in unnamed namespaces instead of using the static keyword. What if you use unnamed namespaces? what does your c_cpp_properties.json look like? do you have one? are you using a configuration provider?

if you think this is a bug, I'd suggest raising an issue ticket with a repro. I don't see any existing tickets tracking this from a quick search in their issue tracker. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=label%3A%22Feature%3A+Find+All+References%22+static.

Thank you for looking into this. I'm not sure what to do about unnamed namespaces in C language.
I only have code that I can't open to the public, so I'll make a code example and raise an issue if it looks like a bug.

if you end up raising an issue ticket, please add a link to it here
